# sequel to postgres database data types. Array?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

Here is my migration file for Sequel:

```
Sequel.migration do
  change do
    create_table(:payloads) do
      primary_key   :id
      String        :url
      String        :requestedAt
      Integer       :respondedIn
      String        :referredBy
      String        :requestType
      String        :parameters
      String        :eventName
      String        :userAgent
      Integer       :resolutionWidth
      Integer       :resolutionHeight
      String        :ip

    end
  end
end
```

The :RequestBy value is an empty array. It is not a string and it's causing an error because my table is expecting a String. Is there a data type in Sequel that handles empty arrays? Is there a method call that is called something like Array that converts the value into an array so that I can then insert it into my database?

Comment: Isn't it better to store an array like field as a separate table and link both by ids?

Comment: I have no idea? If I store an array like field in a separate table... how would I store it? Do I call the value a string? Array? Array doesn't exact in Sequel as a data type does it?

Comment: You have to be storing `requestBy` array (with an id) in another table then create yet another table that maps the ids of `paylod` and `requestBy`.

Answer (score 0):

You need the [pg_array extension](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/pg_array_rb.html).

> The pg_array extension adds support for Sequel to handle PostgreSQL's
>   array types.

Sequel tests use the pg_array extension directly. Search for `'PostgreSQL array handling'` in the [Sequel source for the PostgreSQL adapter](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/spec/adapters/postgres_spec.rb).